# Tabs not reopening when closing Safari on iPad with iOS 13.1

Tags: ipad, safari, tabs

Since upgrading to iOS 13.1 on my iPad (5th Gen, 9.5"), whenever I close the Safari app or turn off iPad, my open tabs are NOT restored.

This was working fine before the upgrade. Anyone else or any suggestions? I keep tabs open till I’ve dealt with them. This behaviour is a blow for me.

Comment: Is there something in Safari Settings?

Comment: I'd also check out further updates, there have been two this past week, they're now up to 13.1.2

Answer (score 1):

While it’s not enabled by default, iPadOS has an option for Safari to automatically close open tabs if they’ve not been viewed for a while. Have you accidentally enabled that option and set it for one day? You’ll find it under Settings / Safari / Close Tabs.

Comment: Thanks - I checked that and it is set to MANUAL but still losing tabs on closure. Have checked all the Safari settings but nothing else there about restoring tabs options. I do recall when setting up after the 13.1. Update that I was asked something or other for SAFARI settings - not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more checking - at the time of the upgrade I also set up **Safari iCloud tabs** for the first time. For some reason - maybe because my iMac is so old, I think the tabs disappeared.

Anyhow, I turned off iCloud Safari on the iPad (data from other devices was not showing anyway) then tried. Tabs remain, even after shutdown. I re-enabled iCloud Safari. It kept working OK. But still no data from the other device (iPhone 6)